# Como separar os caracteres de uma string em R?

Tags: string, r

Tenho valores uma string contendo uma data "01/01/2000" quero separar o dia, mês e ano.

```
#Data
#01/01/2000
```

seja

```
#Dia Mês  Ano
#01   01 2000
```

Como faço isso em R?

Comment: Não tenho experiência em R, mas não é só dar um split pela "/" ? Procure por "split in r"

Comment: Obrigado pela dica,... achei esse portal interessante: http://rfunction.com/archives/1499

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente dessa maneira:

```
unlist(strsplit("01/01/2000", "[/]"))
```

ou

```
> strsplit("01/01/2000", "/")
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!

Comment: Se funcionou, marque a pergunta como resolvida e essa resposta como a solução.

Answer (score 3):

Pra qualquer transformação relacionada a strings eu sugiro o `stringr`.
A função `str_split` sempre retorna uma lista, independente se recebe um vetor com 1 ou mais elementos.

```
> stringr::str_split(rep('01/01/2000', 5), '/')
[[1]]
[1] "01"   "01"   "2000"

[[2]]
[1] "01"   "01"   "2000"

[[3]]
[1] "01"   "01"   "2000"

[[4]]
[1] "01"   "01"   "2000"

[[5]]
[1] "01"   "01"   "2000"
```